# Upload file using Dropzone in react.js component to backend in sails.js

Tags: reactjs, upload, sails.js, dropzone.js, multipart

The backend of my app uses `sails.js`, and there's an API `api/question/new` for creating a new question. This API supports uploading a file or a picture by using its `skipper` module [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper), which I've verified working in the REST client `PostMan` using a file field for upload along with text fields for `title`, `content`, and `tags`.

Now, I am trying to make my react.js-based component (Question Form) work for posting text and uploading file at the same time. I came across a nice library called `react-dropzone` [here](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone), and I am trying to integrate it with my form. The form in react.js is handled by a saga function for posting with the `whatwg-fetch` [library](https://github.com/github/fetch).

**Question Form Component:**

```
export const fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags', 'images'];

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.title) {
        errors.title = 'Required';
    }
    if (!values.content) {
        errors.content = 'Required';
    } else if (values.content.length < 2) { // TODO: specify a constant for length of content
        errors.content = 'Question is too short';
    }

    return errors;
}

class QuestionForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.dropFile = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    }

    onDrop(files) {
        console.log('received files: ', files);
        this.props.fields.images = [];
        files.forEach((file) => {
            this.props.fields.images.push(file);
        });
    }

  render() {
      const { fields: {title, content, tags, images}, resetForm, handleSubmit, submitting, pristine} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={ styles.QuestionForm }>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Row>
                  <label>Title</label>
                  <div>
                      <input className="form-control" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Title" {...title} name="title" />
                  </div>
                  {title.touched && title.error && <div>{title.error}</div>}
              </Row>
              <Row>
                  <label>Content</label>
                  <div>
                      <input className="form-control" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Content" {...content} name="content" />
                  </div>
                  {content.touched && content.error && <div>{content.error}</div>}
              </Row>
              <Row>
                  <label>Tags</label>
                  <div>
                      <input className="form-control" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Tags" {...tags} name="content" />
                  </div>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                   <Dropzone onDrop={this.dropFile}>
                      <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                    </Dropzone>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                  <label></label>
                  <button className="btn btn-warning" type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={resetForm}>Clear Values</button>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
              </Row>
          </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Below is the saga function for posting the form data with whatwg-fetch:**

```
export function* askQuestion() {
    while(true) {
        const action = yield take(types.SUBMIT_QUESTION);
        let askQUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/api/question/new';
        const curToken = getJwtToken();
        var formData = new FormData();

        action.questionObj.images.forEach(function(img) {
            formData.append('images', img);
        });

        formData.append('title', action.questionObj.title);
        formData.append('content', action.questionObj.content);
        formData.append('tags', action.questionObj.tags);
        console.info('formData: ', formData); // here the images field shows as undefined
        try {
            let options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                // body: JSON.stringify(action.questionObj),
                body: formData,
            };
            const response = yield call(request, askQUrl, options);
            if (response.data) {
                yield put(submitQuestionSuccess(response.data));
            } else {
                yield put(submitQuestionFailed(response.error));
            }
        } catch(e) {
            yield put(submitQuestionFailed('server problem in taking your question'));
        }
    }
}
```

When I submit the form with the title/content/tags and a file, I got the following errors in the browser console:

> uncaught at askQuestion   TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of
>   undefined

I am not sure why the `action.questionObj.images` is undefined, because in the `dropFile()` function, I push the file into the images array. Could anyone spot where I am doing wrong? or is there a better way to post both text and file same time to sails.js-based backend?

Comment: I can't see the `dropFile()` function and also no images being pushed to `action.questionObj.images`.

Comment: This line in constructor `this.dropFile = this.onDrop.bind(this);`